# Cannot enable OPcache on MacOS Sierra with PHP 7

Tags: php, macos-sierra, php-7, php-ini, opcache

I am finding it tricky to enable OPcache on my MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) system.

`php --ini` shows the ini file used:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-pdo_pgsql.ini
```

My `php.ini` looks like this:

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=1
```

However, when I look at `phpinfo()` it shows the following:
[image]
[image]

I've restarted Apache after making the change to my `php.ini` to include opcache, but it doesn't appear to be recognised.

I installed PHP with Homebrew, not MAMP although I do have MAMP install but unused.

Comment: Which `php.ini` file did you edit?  The CLI config file is in `/usr/local/etc/`, but your Apache config file is in `/usr/local/php5/lib/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this eventually...

In the output from `phpinfo()`, have a look at the .ini files listed under:

```
Additional .ini files parsed
```

There may be something like

> /usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini

Make sure `opcache.enable=1` is set in this file.